# Implementation of Promise.race()

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I came across [an implementation](https://eddmann.com/posts/implementing-promise-all-and-promise-race-in-javascript/) of the `Promise.race()` method in JavaScript, which works as expected, but doesn't make much sense to me.

```
const race = (...promises) =>
    new Promise((res, rej) => {
        promises.forEach(p => p.then(res).catch(rej));
});
```

How does the `forEach` loop end up assigning **a specific promise**'s functions?

Comment: What do you mean by "assigning a specific promise's functions"?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/29491617/1225328.

Comment: @riwu the constructor of a promise requires a `resolve` and `reject` functions

Comment: @sp00m Thank you. Now I understand that once a Promise is resolved or rejected it's no longer re-assignable. But how does the above implementation result in this happening?

Comment: I would not call that "working as expected". It works very different from the native `Promise.race`.

Comment: @Bergi how is it working differently?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Most importantly, it takes multiple arguments instead of an iterable. Also it's missing to `Promise.resolve()` the values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition a promise resolves / rejects only once, no matter how often you call `resolve` or `reject`. Therefore the promise you construct will resolve to whatever the first promise of the promises passed resolves.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you could make a simpler example, assign some new names for the variables and it would be more graspable.

```
const race = ([A, B, C]) =>
    const outer = new Promise((resolveRace, rejectRace) => {
        A.then(resolveRace).catch(rejectRace); // A wins 
        B.then(resolveRace).catch(rejectRace); // B wins 
        C.then(resolveRace).catch(rejectRace); // C wins 
    }
    return outer;
});
```

For each of the "inner" promises, we assign the success/error callbacks to the "outer" Promise `resolveRace` and `rejectRace` functions.