# What is the reason to allow multiple resolve/reject in ES6 Promise

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I found that is possible (in ES6 promises, while Promise object is created) to use multiple resolve/reject which will affect PromiseStatus only once but not affect execution flow.

```
var p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
    setTimeout(function(){
        resolve(1);
        console.log('Resolve 1');
    }, 50);
    setTimeout(function(){
        resolve(2);
        console.log('Resolve 2');
    }, 100);
});

setTimeout(function(){
        console.log('Status #1:', p);
    }, 10);
setTimeout(function(){
        console.log('Status #2:', p);
    }, 60);
setTimeout(function(){
        console.log('Status #3:', p);
    }, 110);

p.then(function(x){
    console.log('Value after:', x)
})
```

In `then()` functions first resolve/reject will affect execution flow.
So my question is - why it works like this (feature/bug)?

P.S. My env is Node 4.1

P.P.S. My output:

```
Status #1: Promise { <pending> }
Resolve 1
Value after: 1
Status #2: Promise { 1 }
Resolve 2
Status #3: Promise { 1 }
```

Comment: not feature, not bug, there's nothing in the specification of Promise/A+ to suggest that a subsequent attempt to resolve or reject is in any way an error, just that once fulfilled/rejected, the promise remains fulfilled/rejected with an immutable value/reason

Comment: Whats the console output you're seeing given your code example?

Comment: I think you misunderstand the key principle of Promise - `then` callbacks are only fired once, when the Promise is resolved (either fulfilled or rejected). And that's the case here, you can easily check it in the console; even though `resolve(2)` line is executed, the corresponding `then` argument function is not invoked.

Comment: @raina77ow - that's not quite accurate. a) you can have multiple then's on a single promise, b) the `then` can be "added" after the promise is resolved

Comment: Of course, but each action passed into `then` is called only once. That's what I meant actually. )

Comment: What was unexpected to me is to see `Resolve 2` line before the `Value after`... line. It means invokation of `then` action is deferred. Still, it's explainable: otherwise one cannot predict whether a Promise will be resolved in a synchronous or asynchronous way.

Comment: My main question is about execution flow after reject/resolve, for example ability to resolve for the second time and print 'Resolve 2' text. All promise libs I use before at least did not allow to execute after resolve.

Comment: `did not allow to execute after resolve` - that doesn't sound possible - can't see how that could even be written in javascript

Comment: @JaromandaX here it is:
`p.then(function(x){
    x.resolve(1);
    console.log('Value after:', x)
})`
no console out

Comment: if x is an object without a resolve function then you'll get an error of course, but that's a highly unusual pattern you've posted there

Comment: Of course you can *attempt* to resolve twice, doesn't mean it will actually stick. Your above example `x.resolve` should fail with an exception since `resolve` is not exposed on the promise object nor its result. *That's* why the following output is not happening.

Comment: @deceze - x isn't usually even a promise (sorry, a deferred) at that point, it's the value of the fulfilled promise

Comment: @Jar Exactly, *"...nor its result."*

Comment: @deceze - yeah, figured that out after I posted :p

Comment: I used x.resolve to show difference between execution flow in _then_ resolve function and in Promise _executor_ resolve.
Never used this kind of construction before, always only "return"

Comment: Please clearly spell out what you *expect* to be happening here. Seems to me we're beating around the bush and we're not even sure which bush that is.

Comment: `then resolve function` - `then` doesn't have a `resolve` function - I think you haven't quite grasped the Promise concept

Comment: I expect execution will stop after first _resolve_ in  Promise executor function (line #3) and promise flow will continue execution in then(res,rej)

Comment: Well, that's not how Promises work or can work. They're all normal Javascript functions, a function execution can't be killed externally. All a promise does is allow you to synchronise the execution of two dependent asynchronous pieces of code (have `then` wait until another piece of code gives the signal). Nothing more, nothing less. Doesn't mean the signaller is or should be killed.

Comment: Ok so I missed because of dojo.promise or node-promise produces error on second resolve try. Thank you all!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What if i reject / resolve multiple times in Kriskowal's q?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18217640/1048572), but I think we also have a question somewhere that details why `resolve` doesn't throw when being called a second time

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, I want to talk about the *why*. Promises are proxies for single values so running handlers a second time or changing the value doesn't make sense. You can't change the number 5 to be the number 3 for instance.

Let's talk about what alternatives we have for `resolve` being called a second time. Let's say we didn't want to allow it - how would we signal that?

Normally, we'd `throw` - the problem is - it would be caught *nowhere* since `throw`s in the promise constructor get converted to rejections. `.catch` handlers would not run because the promise already resolved.

So we can't really throw as that'd mean an exception you can't handle (a very bad place to be). We can't run handlers twice (that would break the model). So our only choice left is to allow it.

Comment: But why can't we resolve the same promise second time with a new value? What's the reason behind having only the first resolve to be in effect? If multiple resolves were allowed then we could have something like streaming data!

Comment: @FaizHalde a function can only return one value (and it is done one it is returned). If you want to use streaming APIs take a look at async iterators (stage 3) or observables (stage 1)

Comment: @FaizHalde you should check Observers which are a little similar to promises but can emit multiple values over the time. I just came across it recently and am going through it myself.

Answer (score 8):

As per the ECMAScript 2015 Specification, sections [Promise Reject Functions](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promise-reject-functions) and [Promise Resolve Functions](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promise-resolve-functions) say that,

> 4. If *alreadyResolved*.[[value]] is **true**, return **undefined**.

So, if the current promise object is already resolved, then neither resolve, nor reject do anything to the Promise object. It actually means that, only the first resolve/reject matter.