# JavaScript Promise resolve and reject function call sequence

Tags: javascript, promise

I am confused with below simple Promise example.

Question 1: From the console log, why the resolve is executed after the console.log("200") statement?

Question 2: Enable the resolve() before onload() and make the GET request against with an invalid url. Even the AJAX returned with 404, the reject won't be called this time since the resolve before onload is called. Why won't reject be called ?

https://jsfiddle.net/tut5va0m/3/

```
function get(url) {
  // Return a new promise.
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    // Do the usual XHR stuff
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('GET', url);

    //Enable below for Question 2
    //resolve(req.response);
    req.onload = function() {

      // This is called even on 404 etc
      // so check the status
      if (req.status == 200) {

        //Question 1
        resolve(req.response);

        console.log("200");
      }
      else {
        // Otherwise reject with the status text
        // which will hopefully be a meaningful error
        reject(Error(req.statusText));
      }
    };

    // Handle network errors
    req.onerror = function() {
      reject(Error("Network Error"));
    };

    // Make the request
    req.send();
  });
}

function resolve(data) {
console.log("Success!!! " + data);
}

function reject(data) {
console.log("Fail!!! " + data);
}

var url = '/echo/json';
var invalidUrl = '/abc'
get(url).then(resolve, reject);

//below is for Question 2
get(invalidUrl).then(resolve, reject);
```

Comment: `resolve(req.response)` *is* called before the `console.log("200")`? Do you mean the onsuccess `then` handler? Are you confusing yourself because you have multiple functions named `resolve`?

Comment: change the name of the params and you'll see the magic: `return new Promise(function(ree, rejj) {`

Comment: Please don't ask two questions at once. Separate questions are more useful to others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promises are generally used for asynchronous operations, so a line that follows a promise operation (such as `.then`) will execute before the promise handler is executed. This is behavior that should familiar to you if you're use to callback functions, such as the code wrapped in your `req.onload` function. With your code, what you're seeing is the `Promise.resolve` executing, then the `console.log`, then anything chained to the Promise which in your case has the confusing names `resolve` and `reject` as registered on this line:

```
get(url).then(resolve, reject);
```

It would be more clear to rename those function *afterResolve* and *afterReject* because that's when those function execute. If you want to make sure the `console.log` is executed after the promise is resolved or rejected, you need to put that statement inside of those promise-handling function, or chain another function on and do it there.

```
get(url).then(resolve, reject).then(function(){
    console.log('It worked')
})
```

As for your second question, a promise can only be resolved or rejected *once*. You can't resolve it multiple times, nor can you reject it after it's been resolved. That promise has done its duty after it's been resolved or rejected and calling those functions won't do anything afterwards. You'll need to create new promises after that.

```
get(url).then(function successFirstRequest(){
    return get(someOtherUrl)
}).then(function successSecondRequest(){
   alert('Completed two network requests')
}).catch(err){
   // one of your requests failed
})
```

Answer (score 2):

For Question A, resolve use [process.nextTick()](https://howtonode.org/understanding-process-next-tick),
so it's possible that current function will finish before resolve callback will be called.
It's the reason why you see "200" before "Success"

For question B, a Promise can't be both resolved and rejected.
You have to choose or operation succeed and is resolved or it failed and it's rejected. It's can be both.

Comment: But for question B what is the criterion of judging resolve / reject  ?

Comment: You have to choose if operation success or fail.

Comment: @deepsky: Whatever is called first counts. See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18217640/1048572)