# Angular Unit Test Failing Expected spy

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have below controller to get the books list and single books detail. It's working as expected but the unit test is not working as expected.

**books.controller.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp');

function BooksController($log, $routeParams, BooksService) {

    // we declare as usual, just using the `this` Object instead of `$scope`
    const vm = this;
    const routeParamId = $routeParams.id;

    if (routeParamId) {
        BooksService.getBook(routeParamId)
            .then(function (data) {
                $log.info('==> successfully fetched data for book id:', routeParamId);
                vm.book = data;
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                vm.errorMessage = 'OOPS! Book detail not found';
                $log.error('GET BOOK: SOMETHING GOES WRONG', err)
            });
    }

    BooksService.getBooks()
        .then(function (data) {
            $log.info('==> successfully fetched data');
            vm.books = data;
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            vm.errorMessage = 'OOPS! No books found!';
            $log.error('GET BOOK: SOMETHING GOES WRONG', err)
        });

}
BooksController.$inject = ['$log', '$routeParams', 'BooksService'];
myApp.controller('BooksController', BooksController);
```

**Spec for above controller in which I want to test the getBook(id) service but somehow I am not able to pass the id of book.**

```
describe('Get All Books List: getBooks() =>', () => {
        const errMsg = 'OOPS! No books found!';
        beforeEach(() => {
            // injecting rootscope and controller
            inject(function (_$rootScope_, _$controller_, _$q_, BooksService) {
                $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
                $service = BooksService;
                $q = _$q_;
                deferred = _$q_.defer();

                // Use a Jasmine Spy to return the deferred promise
                spyOn($service, 'getBooks').and.returnValue(deferred.promise);

                // The injector unwraps the underscores (_) from around the parameter names when matching
                $vm = _$controller_('BooksController', {$scope: $scope, $service: BooksService});
            });

        });

        it('should defined getBooks $http methods in booksService', () => {
            expect(typeof $service.getBooks).toEqual('function');
        });

        it('should able to fetch data from getBooks service', () => {
            // Setup the data we wish to return for the .then function in the controller
            deferred.resolve([{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }]);

            // We have to call apply for this to work
            $scope.$apply();

            // Since we called apply, now we can perform our assertions
            expect($vm.books).not.toBe(undefined);
            expect($vm.errorMessage).toBe(undefined);
        });

        it('should print error message if data not fetched', () => {

            // Setup the data we wish to return for the .then function in the controller
            deferred.reject(errMsg);

            // We have to call apply for this to work
            $scope.$apply();

            // Since we called apply, now we can perform our assertions
            expect($vm.errorMessage).toBe(errMsg);
        });
    });

describe('Get Single Book Detail: getBook() =>', () => {
            const errMsg = 'OOPS! Book detail not found';
            const routeParamId = '59663140b6e5fe676330836c';
            beforeEach(() => {

                // injecting rootscope and controller
                inject(function (_$rootScope_, _$controller_, _$q_, BooksService) {
                    $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
                    $scope.id = routeParamId;
                    $service = BooksService;
                    $q = _$q_;
                    var deferredSuccess = $q.defer();

                    // Use a Jasmine Spy to return the deferred promise
                    spyOn($service, 'getBook').and.returnValue(deferredSuccess.promise);
                    // The injector unwraps the underscores (_) from around the parameter names when matching
                    $vm = _$controller_('BooksController', {$scope: $scope, $service: BooksService});
                });

            });

            it('should defined getBook $http methods in booksService', () => {
                expect(typeof $service.getBook).toEqual('function');

            });

            it('should print error message', () => {
                // Setup the data we wish to return for the .then function in the controller
                deferred.reject(errMsg);

                // We have to call apply for this to work
                $scope.$apply();

                // expect($service.getBook(123)).toHaveBeenCalled();
                // expect($service.getBook(123)).toHaveBeenCalledWith(routeParamId);
                // Since we called apply, now we can perform our assertions
                expect($vm.errorMessage).toBe(errMsg);
            });
        });
```

"Get Single Book Detail: getBook()" this suit is not working. Please help me, how to short out this kind of situation.

Error I am getting is below

```
Chrome 59.0.3071 (Mac OS X 10.12.5) Books Controller Get Single Book Detail: getBook() => should print error message FAILED
        Expected 'OOPS! No books found!' to be 'OOPS! Book detail not found'.
Chrome 59.0.3071 (Mac OS X 10.12.5) Books Controller Get Single Book Detail: getBook() => should print error message FAILED
        Expected 'OOPS! No books found!' to be 'OOPS! Book detail not found'.
            at Object.it (test/client/controllers/books.controller.spec.js:108:38)
 Chrome 59.0.3071 (Mac OS X 10.12.5): Executed 7 of 7 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.068 secs)
.
Chrome 59.0.3071 (Mac OS X 10.12.5): Executed 7 of 7 (1 FAILED) (0.005 secs / 0.068 secs)
```

Answer (score 0):

*EDIT* (removed original, 2am answer)

Are you using `strict` mode? There appear to be a few scoping issues going on:

1. On line 9 (in the "Get All Books List" spec), `deferred` is not declared, making it global implicitly
2. The last test ran on the "Get All Books List" spec fails the global `deferred` promise
3. On line 60 (in the "Get Single Book Detail" spec), `deferredSuccess` is declared with `var` making it local to the function passed to `inject()`
4. On line 70 (the test in question), where (I assume) you meant to reject the "Single Book" `deferredSuccess`, you're actually failing the global/list `deferred` promise. This has no effect, since as mentioned in item 2 that promise was already failed and [Q ignores repeated rejections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18218542/1424869).

So, that should explain why the error is not what you think it should be.

`deferred` isn't the only variable with scoping issues in your example; those should be addressed. I suggest wrapping the file in an [IFFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) and using [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode). It'll make the code more predictable and avoid issues like this.

Doing this will only get you halfway there; @estus's response should round out the job.

Comment: Just to add more detail. The reason you're not seeing the response you're expecting is because you've overridden the method you're testing and explicitly told it to always return `promise.resolve`. It can't return anything but an empty resolved promise.

Comment: It is a controller that is being tested, not a service. Thus a service has to be mocked.

Comment: Updated with more correct answer. That's what I get for answering questions at 2am...

Answer (score 0):

you need to mock `$rootScope.` with provide.

The value of `id` is not getting avaibale in controller which is `undefined`.

So, non-id condition getting executing.

```
   $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
   $scope.id = routeParamId;
   module(function ($provide) {
     $provide.value('$rootScope', scope); //mock rootscope with id
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Real router should never be used in unit tests, with `ngRoute` module preferably be excluded from tested modules.

`$scope.id = routeParamId` is assigned before controller instantiation, but it isn't used at all. Instead, it should be done with mocked `$routeParams`.

There's no `$service` service. It's called `BooksService`. Thus `getBooks` isn't a spy. It's preferable to mock the service completely, not only a single method.

```
mockedBooksService = jasmine.createSpyObj('BooksService', ['getBooks']);

var mockedData1 = {};
var mockedData2 = {};
mockedBooksService.getBooks.and.returnValues(
  $q.resolve(mockedData1),
  $q.resolve(mockedData2),
);
$vm = $controller('BooksController', {
  $scope: $scope,
  BooksService: mockedBooksService,
  $routeParams: { id: '59663140b6e5fe676330836c' }
});

expect(mockedBooksService.getBooks).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
expect(mockedBooksService.getBooks.calls.allArgs()).toEqual([
  ['59663140b6e5fe676330836c'], []
]);

$rootScope.$digest();

expect($vm.book).toBe(mockedData2);

// then another test for falsy $routeParams.id
```

The test reveals the problem in controller code. Since tested code is called on controller construction, `$controller` should be called every time in `it`. A good way to avoid this is to put initialization code into `$onInit` method that could be tested separately.