# why resolve function runs once in thenable

Tags: javascript, promise, thenable

Helo, I'm trying to understand promises and don't understand why this code:

```
class Thenable {
  constructor(num) {
    this.num = num;
  }
  then(resolve, reject) {
    console.log(resolve); // function() { native code }
    // resolve with this.num*2 after the 3 second
    new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
       setTimeout(() => resolve(this.num * 2), 3000); // (**)
    }).then((ret)=>{ resolve('wow'); resolve('inside '+ret)})
  }
}

new Promise(resolve => resolve(1))
  .then(result => {
    return new Thenable(result); // (*)
  })
  .then((r) => { console.log(r) } ); 
console.log('done')
```

prints only 'wow' and don't print 'inside 2' :

```
done 
ƒ () {}
wow
```

*Thenable.then* is an ordinary function, when I call it with  `.then((r) => { console.log(r) } )` the *resolve* became function with one argument who calls *console.log* .
Why it calls only first *resolve('wow')* and doesn't call next *resolve('inside '+ret)* ?
Does js engine somehow rewrite my *.then* function and left only one *resolve* invocation?

Comment: You can resolve promise only once, later calls to `resolve` will be just ignored

Comment: https://humanwhocodes.com/blog/2020/09/creating-javascript-promise-from-scratch-constructor/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18217640/what-happens-if-i-reject-resolve-multiple-times

Answer (score 3):

Promises can only settle (resolve or reject) once. When you pass back a thenable, the resolution function converts the Thenable result to a native Promise, which only resolves once even if your thenable calls the resolution function multiple times.

---

From your question:

> the *resolve* became function with one argument who calls *console.log*

That's not true. *resolve* is the function that resolves the internal native Promise created by the `then` call above your line `(*)`, as in [the MDN docs for the Promise constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/Promise#the_resolve_function):

> If [the resolution function]'s called with a thenable value (including another `Promise` instance), then the thenable's `then` method is saved and called in the future (it's always called asynchronously). The `then` method will be called with two callbacks, which are two new functions with the exact same behaviors as the `resolveFunc` and `rejectFunc` passed to the `executor` function. If calling the `then` method throws, then the current promise is rejected with the thrown error.

Even if your Thenable implementation can resolve multiple times (against spec), the native Promise created by [`then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#return_value) and [`Promise.resolve`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve#return_value) can only resolve once, and that Promise is the one that your `console.log` handler is chained onto. From [the same Promise constructor docs above](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/Promise#effect_of_calling_resolvefunc):

> Calling `resolveFunc` causes the promise to become resolved, so that calling `resolveFunc` or `rejectFunc` again has no effect.